# How to present activityViewController from UICollectionView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4, uiactivityviewcontroller

I currently have a `UICollectionView` where I want to be able to present an `activityViewController` to enable sharing (not from a cell, but from `UIView` within the collectionView). The problem is the below code does not work because `present()` is a viewController method.

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [test], applicationActivities: nil)
present(activityViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

I have tried creating an instance of a `viewController` to call `present()` with, however that does not work, because it isn't in the view hierarchy.

The closest thing to an answer I've found is a mention of a weak delegate, but I am not sure how to make that work.

Looking for any ideas on how to make this work. Thanks

**Update**
My hierarchy consists of a viewController `HomeViewController`, I then display a collectionView `routeDetailCollectionView` on the bottom half of the screen. Within `routeDetailCollectionView` I have a UIView `routeHeaderView` a that contains UIButton `shareButton`. I want to present the ios share menu when `shareButton` is pressed.

Comment: where you are presenting `UIActivityViewController`? pls add code.

Comment: You have to present it from visibleViewController. You can get it from the  UIcollectionview's superview if is directly added inside the main view.

Comment: @MehulSojitra the collectionView is added on top of a homeViewController, so I don't think it has a true superview

Comment: @ivarun I tried to make it a little more clear about my setup, but the code is part of a large app and so posting more code would probably make this more complicated than it needs to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get `rootViewController` from `UIApplication` by using below method

```
func topMostController() -> UIViewController {
  var rootViewController: UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
  while (rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {
    rootViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController!
  }
  return rootViewController
}
```

After that, use `rootViewController` to present `UIActivityViewController`

```
let rootViewController = topMostController()

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [test], applicationActivities: nil)
rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: I thought this would work, but it still gives me -> Warning: Attempt to present <UIActivityViewController: 0x7fc3fa84d600> on <UINavigationController: 0x7fc3fb813200> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0):

You could use delegate to communicate with parent viewcontroller & present from there. Oru if you are using navigation controller, you can present it from there

Comment: I'm not using a navigation controller. How would I go about using delegate?

Comment: I think you can bound an action from uibutton to homeviewcontroller.

Comment: When I tried to do that, it through an error because homeViewController isn't in the same view hierarchy